# Modify MDT wizard to automate computer naming

Tags: windows-server-2008, vbscript, html, xml, mdt-2010

Situation:

> I am imaging new systems using MDT Lite-Touch. I am trying to
>   customize the wizard to automate the naming of new systems so that
>   they include a prefix "AG-", a department code which is selected from
>   a drop-down box in the wizard page (eg. "FOO"), and finally the
>   serial number of the computer being imaged, so that my result in this
>   case would be "AG-FOO-1234567"

Status:

> I have banged away at this for a while but my Google searches have not
>   turned up answers, my trial-and-error is not producing useful error
>   messages and I think I am missing some fundamentals of how to get
>   variables from the wizard page into the variables used by the
>   lite-touch wizard.

Progress:

> 1. I first created the HTML page which I will include below and added a script to the page to concatenate the pieces into a variable called
>      OSDComputername which, for testing, I could output in a msgbox and get
>      to display correctly.
>
>    - The problem with this is I don't know how to trigger the script then assign it to the OSDComputername variable that is used throughout
>        the rest of the Light-Touch process.
> 2. I changed the script to a function and added it to DeployWiz_Initization.vbs then used the Initialization field in WDS to
>      call it. I'll include the function below.
>
>    - The problem with this is I would get "Undefined Variable" for OSDComputername and I am not sure it is pulling the data from the HTML
>        correctly.
> 3. I tried adding the scripting into the customsettings.ini file after the "OSDComputername="
>
>    - This resulted in the wizard just outputting my code in text as the computer name.
> 4. I tried adding variables to "Properties=" (eg.DepartmentName) in the customsettings.ini, pulling thier value from the HTML Form and setting that value to the variable in my function in DeployWiz_Initization.vbs and calling them after "OSDComputername=" in the fashion "OSDComputername="AG-" & %DepartmentName%" in customsettings.ini
>
>    - This resulted in errors from my script which did not correctly access the new variables
> 5. I now have my code working. It is pulling the data from the HTML and setting the OSDComputername environment variable. I have updated the code below to match the working code. It is firing correctly and setting my computer name and description exactly as I wanted it to.

Issue Resolved!

The HTML page:

```
<H1>Configure the computer name.</H1>
<p>Please answer the following questions.  Your answers will be used to formulate the computer's name and description.</p>

<FORM NAME="SetComputerNameForm">
    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">D</u>epartmental Prefix:</LABEL><br />
        <SELECT NAME="DepartmentalPrefix_Edit" ID="DepartmentalPrefix_Edit" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=D>
            <option value="FOO">FOO</option>
            <option value="DOE">DOE</option>
            <option value="AFK">AFK</option>
            <option value="BBL">BBL</option>
            <option value="RTFM">RTFM</option>                  
        </SELECT>
    </p>


    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">C</u>lient's ID:</LABEL>
        <br />
        <INPUT NAME="ClientID" ID="ClientID" TYPE="text" ID="ClientID" SIZE="15" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=C />
        <label class=ErrMsg for=ClientID>* Required (MISSING)</label>


    </p>


    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">B</u>uilding:</LABEL><br />
        <SELECT NAME="Building_Edit" ID="Building_Edit" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName  AccessKey=B>
                <option value="ASA">ASA</option>
                <option value="ASB">ASB</option>
                <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
        </SELECT>
    </p>


    <p>         
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">R</u>oom Number:</span></LABEL>
        <br />
        <INPUT NAME="RoomNumber" ID="RoomNumber" TYPE="text" ID="RoomNumber" size="15" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=R>
        <label class=ErrMsg for=RoomNumber>* Required (MISSING)</label>
    </p>

</FORM>
```

The Function:

```
Function ValidateSetComputerName
    ParseAllWarningLabels

    If Len(Document.SetComputerNameForm.ClientNetID.Value) < 1 OR Len(Document.SetComputerNameForm.RoomNumber.Value) < 1 THEN
        ButtonNext.disabled = true
    Else
        Dim Department
        Dim SerialNumber
        Dim CID
        Dim RoomNumber
        Dim BuildingName
        Dim Make
        Dim Model
        Department = Document.SetComputerNameForm.DepartmentalPrefix_Edit.Value
        SerialNumber = oEnvironment.Item("SerialNumber")
        CID = Document.SetComputerNameForm.ClientID.Value
        RoomNumber = Document.SetComputerNameForm.RoomNumber.Value
        BuildingName = Document.SetComputerNameForm.Building_Edit.Value
        Make = oEnvironment.Item("Make")
        Model = oEnvironment.Item("Model")

        oEnvironment.Item("OSDComputerName") = "AG-" & Department & "-" & Right(SerialNumber,7)
        oEnvironment.Item("ComputerDescription") = Department & ", " & CID & ", " & RoomNumber & " " & BuildingName & ", " & Make & " " & Model
        ButtonNext.disabled = false
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but `AG-COMM-1234567890` is too long. The length limit for a Windows computer name is 15 characters. That could be *part* of your issue or could crop up once you've gotten past this hurdle.

Comment: Right. I will need to trim the serial number to the last 7 characters. (In looking at my systems, all of them already are 7 characters, but probably not a bad idea to restrict this in my script just in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. I have updated the code above to reflect the changes I made.